# Maven Mojo leaks static information to subsequent executions

Tags: java, maven, jvm, classloader, maven-plugin

I am working on a Maven compiler plug-in for a new programming language. Like with other Maven compiler plug-ins, this plug-in is invoked in different phases of a module build (e.g., `compile`, `test-compile`), and for multiple modules during a reactor build. The language has a "bootstrap" component that stores certain static information which includes `Class` and `ClassLoader` objects. The information stored in this bootstrap component is not reusable across multiple executions of the compiler plug-in (it needs to be freshly generated each time). Currently, compilation fails because invalid information from an earlier execution is picked up (e.g., the `test-compile` execution might use some information left over from the earlier `compile` phase).

I realize that there are a number of different ways to solve such an issue (e.g., handle the currently static information in a different way, or provide some way of wiping it out between phases, etc.). My question here is primarily about Maven-specific ways to address this sort of problem.

The default [instantiation strategy](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugin-descriptor.html#:%7E:text=This%20property%20is,retrieved%20from%20Plexus.) already creates a new plug-in instance every time, but that doesn't help in my case since the static data is not in the Maven plug-in itself, but in the compiler library that it depends on (come to think of it, I don't think it would help with static data either way). Another option would be to start a separate JVM for each execution, similar to the `<fork>` option of the Maven Compiler Plugin, but it appears that this existing mechanism is not easily reusable and would have to be essentially re-created from scratch.

Is there a Maven mechanism to isolate data (and loaded classes) between different executions of the same plug-in?